# Application crash on device but works fine on iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, crash, sigabrt

My app worked fine on my device but I have added features and when I test on my device (iphone 4 iOs 4.2.1), it crashes just on launching; But it works fine on simulator.
I have looked for an answer to my question on the web and this forum but I don't find...

Here is the crash report :

```
Incident Identifier: 7204BFE3-E826-438E-8B3E-78301DE6AA99
CrashReporter Key:   06d77d7d3219de2a9a56c2fa0510b92310e5da62
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         ColorMixer [1074]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/AD6EC67E-FCBE-4D02-8EE3-06153233CA2E/ColorMixer.app/ColorMixer
Identifier:      ColorMixer
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  punchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-05-20 00:02:28.738 +0200
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd52d4 __kill + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd52c4 kill + 4
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd52b6 raise + 10
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33be9d72 abort + 50
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bdba20 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3347c594 _objc_terminate + 104
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bd9df2 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bd9e46 std::terminate() + 10
8   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bd9f16 __cxa_throw + 78
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3347b4c4 objc_exception_throw + 64
10  CoreFoundation                  0x33ac07c2 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 62
11  CoreFoundation                  0x33ac07fc +[NSException raise:format:] + 28
12  UIKit                           0x3224b77c -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1104
13  UIKit                           0x3224cb32 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 86
14  UIKit                           0x3209e86a -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFile] + 90
15  Backgrounder.dylib              0x00090b4c 0x8f000 + 6988
16  UIKit                           0x3209a1f6 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 174
17  UIKit                           0x32066484 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1108
18  UIKit                           0x32065ec2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 38
19  UIKit                           0x32065900 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5084
20  GraphicsServices                0x33b0eefc PurpleEventCallback + 660
21  CoreFoundation                  0x33a556f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
22  CoreFoundation                  0x33a556bc __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160
23  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47f76 __CFRunLoopRun + 514
24  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
25  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
26  UIKit                           0x32099302 -[UIApplication _run] + 374
27  UIKit                           0x32096e8c UIApplicationMain + 664
28  ColorMixer                      0x00002c70 main (main.m:23)
29  ColorMixer                      0x00002c18 start + 32

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b89974 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c33704 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 88
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c33174 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 96
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c32b98 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd724a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcf970 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd79e0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd7364 _pthread_wqthread + 540
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcf970 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x304df124 RunWebThread(void*) + 332
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start + 242
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x3eaf12e8
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x31bd9989      r6: 0x001667ac      r7: 0x2fdfe024
    r8: 0x3ea4f538    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x0015c6b0     r11: 0x00000001
    ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x2fdfe024      lr: 0x33bd52cb      pc: 0x33bd52d4
  cpsr: 0x00080010
```

I don't know what I have to do, I don't see references to my code...
Thanks for future help.

Comment: It's not in your code, it's in your main NIB. Somewhere an exception is being thrown. A possibility is that you have a view controller which is supposed to be loaded from another NIB, but that NIB doesn't exist. It could still work in the simulator because the old resources aren't deleted if they aren't used anymore.

Comment: Try resetting contents and setting from the menu options in simulator. you will know the issue as ughoavgfhw commented.

Comment: You might try deleting the app off of your device before running it again.

Answer (score 0):

See this post to add `NSZombieEnabled`, that will provide you more infos on the crash.

[App crash only on iPhone Device and not in Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427516/app-crash-only-on-iphone-device-and-not-in-simulator/8428331#8428331)